# Python list remove method: how's the implementation?

Tags: python, list, compare

In java, I have my client class that have the "code" attr, and the equals method. Method equals receives another client and compares with itself's code attr.

In python, I just read that we have the `__cmp__` method, to do the same as java method equals. Ok, I did that. I created my class client, with "code" attr and the method comp that verify if the code is the same.

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def __cmp__(self, obj):
        return obj.code == self.code

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.code)
```

Then I put 3 Client objects in a python's list:

```
bla = [Client(1), Client(2), Client(3)]
```

Then, when I try:

```
bla.remove(Client(3))
```

The amazing python removes the first element (the Client with code 1).

What I am doing wrong? I searched the implementation of list in python's Lib files, but is not easy to find.

Anyone can help?

Comment: That method is called `__cmp__`. Perhaps you could show your implementation of that method?

Comment: @Daniel Your comment most probably contains the right answer.  Consider copying it as an actual answer so that we can upvote you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

> `__cmp__(self, other)`
>
> Called by comparison operations if
>   rich comparison (see above) is not
>   defined. Should return a negative
>   integer if self < other, zero if self
>   == other, a positive integer if self > other.

Basically, you should change your implementation of `__cmp__` to be...

```
def __cmp__(self, obj):
    return cmp(obj.code, self.code)
```

The `cmp()` builtin function of Python is specifically designed to return the values that `__cmp__` is expected to return by comparing its two arguments.

There is also a different function in Python called `__eq__` which only checks equality, for which your current implementation of `__cmp__` would be better suited.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you actually want `__eq__`

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        return obj.code == self.code

    # this is how you usually write cmp, Amber explained the problem
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.code, other.code)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.code)
```

Btw, what happens in your buggy example is that `__cmp__` returns False as expected. But in Python `False == 0` and returning 0 from `__cmp__` means the compared elements are equal. So that is why it removes the first element!